# Cant add images to JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

> I've been trying to add an array of images to a JPanel and then add
> that JPanel to JFrame. I couldn't figure it out, so now I made a
> JFrame Form, added a JPanel there and tried to customize the code.
>
> I have a class named Game that only has one attribute called "img",
> which is a string of the image url; 
> gameArray is an ArrayList of Game where I added the objects.

> ["mainPanel" is the panel I added in JFrame Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea1kC.png) 
> [this is the custom code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKNt3.png) 
> [this is the error i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAVm9.png)
>
> The objective is: I create many "Game" objects. One of the attributes
> is an img url (String), and I want to display those images in JFrame.
> (Like Steam maybe? or other game stores(if that's how you say it xD))
> I'm sorry if this is not clear enough. My english is not great hehe.

Comment: Since you've not provided a [mcve], I would "guess" that `Game#getImg` is returning `void`

Comment: @MadProgrammer not really, because I did a system.out.print(game.getImg()) and it printed the url...I'm clearly doing something wrong but I dont know what.

Comment: Then, please, post a [mcve] which demonstrates your issue and removes all the ambiguity

Comment: `new JLabel().setIcon(...)` <- `setIcon` returns `void`.   Use the constructor variant  instead, [`JLabel(Icon)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLabel.html#%3Cinit%3E(javax.swing.Icon))